# pg_relation_size tells me column doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-admin.html says:

> pg_relation_size
>   accepts the OID or name of a table, index or toast table, and returns the size in bytes

However when I use it with a valid table name, I get the error:

> **column** [table] does not exist...

I know my table exists, because doing

```
SELECT count(*) FROM [table]
```

returns a valid number. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitely adding the schema (e.g. 'public') where the table is located in the pg_relation_size call.

Like this (untested):

```
select pg_relation_size(public.mytablename) from pg_tables
```

Comment: You may need to do use '': select pg_relation_size('public.mytablename') from pg_tables

Comment: i am a doofus! i had double quotes ... thanks again, works now.

Comment: ps 'from pg_tables' is not necessary, your first answer (unedited) was correct.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error though the cause was different. pg_relation_size is case insensitive, so if you have anything other than lower case it will not work out of the box:

```
postgres=> SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('MyTable'));
ERROR:  relation "mytable" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('mytable...
                                                     ^
postgres=> SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"MyTable"'));
 pg_size_pretty
----------------
 225 MB
(1 row)
```

So in order for this to work in a SELECT statement you need to enclose the table name in quotes:

```
postgres=> SELECT relname, nspname, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('"' || relname || '"')) 
  FROM pg_class c LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace  
  WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','') AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast') AND pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) 
  ORDER BY c.relpages DESC;
```

Comment: i had to write it like this: `select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"MyTable"'));` that is, the table name is both double and single quoted.